# Moving data from around 600 tables from one database to other

Tags: ssis

I got a database with 650 tables and need to move the data from these tables to tables in another database. Table names are same in the two databases. We need to add a small transformation(Need to prefix text in one of the columns) in between. I am using SSIS to transfer the data. I think it is very hard to have 650 dataflows. Is there any easy way to have the data transferred along with the transformation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use only one "Transfer SQL server objects" to copy schema and data from the 650 tables, it's very fast and simple.

[image: Transfer SQL server objects]

Then use a simple sql task to add the prefix.

Comment: I have 4 similar databases from which I have to copy the data to the destination. The destination is being used as staging area. the prefix in a column will be used to identify the source of the record. I think this task will not be useful to me.